# Strange Results while using Proxy with Requests

Tags: python, python-requests, proxy, http-proxy

I am using Proxy in Request Session and Trying to get my IP address of the request got the machine IP not the Proxy IP

```
from sslproxies import get_proxy

proxy = get_proxy(countries=['US'],verify=True , https= True)


print (proxy.ip_and_port)
url = 'https://api.ipify.org'


proxy_dict = {'http':'http://'+proxy.ip_and_port }
print (proxy_dict)

try:
    s = requests.session()
    headers = {'User-Agent':generate_user_agent()}
    s.proxies.update(proxy_dict)
    response = s.get(url, headers = headers , proxies=proxy_dict very)
    assert response.text== proxy.ip_and_port
except Exception as E:
    print (E)
    print("Proxy does not work")
```

Every time Exception raised , What is the reason for this

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the used proxy was using `http` and the requested site uses `https`